# Connect to MYSQL database, retrieve data as JSON and send it to client side via AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, gwt

I am building an interactive web application with GWT, and I've come across a problem. The app is basically going to be a GUI for a database.

**What I'd like to do:**

Populate a MySQL server with data, and serve it via AJAX as a JSON file to my client side code.

**The application life cycle should look like this:**

Query on the client side -> Query the database -> serve up the requested information -> convert it to JSON -> Send back to client side via AJAX -> process on client side

I'd like to make this without refreshing the page, so the database querying should be ajax too.

If someone could point me to the right direction, I'd be really grateful. I've yet to find any good tutorials or examples to this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using GWT:

1° For Data-oriented app you will want to use [GWT RequestFactory](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html)

2° If you want to stick to basic RPC here's what happens:

Fill up a form > Click on a button > make a call using RPC, passing a "shared" object as argument to your call > conversion from JSON to Java is handled by GWT > handle the request and make your query > convert the entity/DTO to a GWT "shared" object > your RPC controller returns the result > conversion to Java to JSON is handled by GWT > typically use a [Celltable](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html) to display the result using a [dataprovider](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html), you won't need to reload the page.

If some parts of the process are unclear feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JSON unless there is some other reason you don't mention. A strong point of GWT is that you can use your entity code in your client side code so all of the client-server communication layer is hidden. Easiest way to do what you are asking:

1. Create @Entity annotated objects for each table
2. Create RPC service that exposes operations client needs
3. Implement database interactions with Objectify
4. Fetch your entities in GWT using RPC client